# ORDER BY and DISTINCT ON (...) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, active-model-serializers

I am trying to ORDER by created_at and then get a DISTINCT set based on a foreign key.

The other part is to somehow use this is ActiveModelSerializer. Specifically I want to be able to declare:

`has_many :somethings`

In the serializer. Let me explain further...

I am able to get the results I need with this custom sql:

```
def latest_product_levels
  sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) client_product_levels.product_id,       
  client_product_levels.* FROM client_product_levels WHERE client_product_levels.client_id = #{id} ORDER BY product_id, 
  client_product_levels.created_at DESC";
  results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

Is there any possible way to get this result but as a condition on a has_many relationship so that I can use it in AMS?

In pseudo code: @client.products_levels
Would do something like: `@client.order(created_at: :desc).select(:product_id).distinct`

That of course fails for reasons that are beyond me.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to structure this is to split your query into two parts: the first part manages the filtering of rows so that you get only your latest client product levels. The second part uses a standard `has_many` association to connect `Client` with `ClientProductLevel`.

Starting with your `ClientProductLevel` model, you can create a scope to do the latest filtering:

```
class ClientProductLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :latest, -> {
    select("distinct on(product_id) client_product_levels.product_id,
                                    client_product_levels.*").
    order("product_id, created_at desc")
  }
end
```

You can use this scope anywhere that you have a query that returns a list of ClientProductLevel objects, e.g., `ClientProductLevel.latest` or `ClientProductLevel.where("created_at < ?", 1.week.ago).latest`, etc.

If you haven't already done so, set up your `Client` class with a `has_many` relationship:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_product_levels
end
```

Then in your ActiveModelSerializer try this:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :client_product_levels

  def client_product_levels
    object.client_product_levels.latest
  end
end
```

When you invoke the `ClientSerializer` to serialize a `Client` object, the serializer sees the `has_many` declaration, which it would ordinarily forward to your `Client` object, but since we've got a locally defined method by that name, it invokes that method instead. (Note that this `has_many` declaration is not the same as an ActiveRecord `has_many`, which specifies a relationship between tables: in this case, it's just saying that the serializer should present an array of serialized objects under the key `client_product_levels'.)

The `ClientSerializer#client_product_levels` method in turn invokes the `has_many` association from the client object, and then applies the `latest` scope to it. The most powerful thing about ActiveRecord is the way it allows you to chain together disparate components into a single query. Here, the `has_many` generates the `where client_id = $X' portion, and the scope generates the rest of the query. Et voila!

In terms of simplification: ActiveRecord doesn't have native support for `distinct on`, so you're stuck with that part of the custom sql. I don't know whether you need to include `client_product_levels.product_id` explicitly in your select clause, as it's already being included by the `*`. You might try dumping it.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I know it's a little off topic here, but would you mind explaining how this works? Looking at the sql on ClientProductLevel looks like it would only return the latest globally. I see the sql that actually gets generated: `SELECT distinct on(product_id) client_product_levels.product_id,
                                    client_product_levels.* FROM "client_product_levels"  WHERE "client_product_levels"."client_id" = $1  ORDER BY product_id, created_at desc  [["client_id", 312]]`. Just would love to understand how this gets created between the scope and the has_many

Comment: Also, is there a way to build this query without the custom sql?

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked. I'll provide a bit more explanation in the answer above. ActiveRecord, AFAIK, does not support the Postgres `distinct on` mechanism, and the alternative way to structure the query using only features natively supported by AR is a total mess.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation. Thank you for taking the time!